# I get ERROR on sql update and delete

Tags: database, oracle

i am new to sql and ...for my assignment i am trying to set up update on cascade and delete on cascade. However it gives me an error saying it's missing a key word

here is my code:

```
DROP TABLE BEACH;
DROP TABLE OCEANS; 

CREATE TABLE OCEANS
(OceanTitle          VARCHAR(18),  
AverageDepth         NUMBER(8),
PrecentOfSurface     NUMBER(8),
CONSTRAINT OCEANS_OceanTitle_pk PRIMARY KEY (OceanTitle));

CREATE TABLE BEACH
(BeachTitle          VARCHAR(18),  
State                VARCHAR(18), 
CONSTRAINT BEACH_BeachTitle_pk PRIMARY KEY (BeachTitle),
CONSTRAINT BEACH_OceanTitle_fk FOREIGN KEY(OceanTitle) REFERENCES OCEANS(OceanTitle),  
OceanTitle VARCHAR(18) REFERENCES OCEANS(OceanTitle) ON update CASCADE,
OceanTitle VARCHAR(18) REFERENCES OCEANS(OceanTitle) ON delete CASCADE 
);

INSERT INTO OCEANS VALUES ('Pacific', 13740, 48);
INSERT INTO OCEANS VALUES ('Atlantic', 12254, 28);
INSERT INTO OCEANS VALUES ('Gulf', 5299, 1);
INSERT INTO BEACH VALUES ('Manele Bay', 'Hawaii', 'Pacific');

INSERT INTO BEACH VALUES ('Myrtle Beach', 'South Carolina', 'Atlantic');
INSERT INTO BEACH VALUES ('Nantucket', 'Massachusetts', 'Atlantic');
INSERT INTO BEACH VALUES ('Clearwater Beach', 'Florida', 'Gulf');
INSERT INTO BEACH VALUES ('Coronado', 'California', 'Pacific');
```

the error message :

```
OceanTitle VARCHAR(18) REFERENCES OCEANS(OceanTitle) ON update CASCADE,
                                                        *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Comment: MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server are three distinct, totally separate DBMSs, with vastly different features, functionality, and syntax. It is impossible for you to be using all three of them simultaneously. Do **not** randomly add tags just because they sound familiar or contain words you recognize. Tags here have specific meaning. Edit your post to include **only** the tag for the **actual DBMS** you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your statement is `On Update Cascade` which is not available in Oracle.

Re execute your statement after removing it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by previous answer, `On Update Cascade` isn't available in Oracle.

Here are some workarounds:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_cascade_update.htm

(tom kyte script) http://tkyte.blogspot.ro/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html

Deffered constraints
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0120__Table/DeferredConstraints.htm

Hope this helps - good luck